# Lenovo s10-3 Xubunutu wireless is disabled by hardware switch

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, lenovo

So I just got rid of Windows 7 starter and installed Xubuntu 12.04 but the network manager after trying to enable wireless says

```
wireless is disabled by hardware switch
```

I have googled around and found no solution.

`rfkill list` says

```
2: phy0: Wireless LAN Hard blocked: yes
```

and `rfkill unblock all` doesn't do anything.

I am also 100% sure my switch on the machine is turned on and the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> combination doesn't fix it either.

I have tried BIOS reset with no luck and rearranging the boot order with also no luck. 
The only way I can connect to the Internet on this machine is through USB smartphone WiFi, I think the cable port is broken.

I have also tried with no luck so far:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
rmmod ath5k && modprobe ath5k
rm /dev/rfkill    
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower auto
```

I'm kind of stuck now and don't know what else to do, my last idea is to reinstall Windows 7 just to turn this WiFi back on but that's the last thing I'd want to do. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the entirety of: rfkill list all

Answer (score 0):

Oh no. I've been there. There's only one solution. You have to either install windows and turn the hardware switch back on. Or the following, and this is what I did. You have to open your netbook and take out the battery to do a CMOS reset. Here's the tutorial I followed:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/577114/comments/31

It was also discussed here:
http://www.linlap.com/lenovo_ideapad_s10-3